# Stripe payment gateway integration in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I use Stripe payment gateway in codeigniter using stripe.js. In stripe payment process first do client side validation and then after server side validation by stripe php 2.1.1 library. Client side validation working ready but server side validation gives error. I put stripe php 2.1.1 folder in codeigniter library folder.

I refer this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe--pre-80957

code:

```
    <?php
$success = "";
$error = "";

require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');

if ($_POST) {
  Stripe::setApiKey("dm_wsdst_yJQB5mrfjpfQX2uMQHf3CbD");
  $error = '';
  $success = '';
  try {
    if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
      throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
    Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => 11,
                                "currency" => "usd",
                                "card" => $_POST['stripeToken']));
    $success = 'Your payment was successful.';
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
  }
}

echo "sucess". isset($success) ? $success : "";
echo "error".isset($error) && $success ? $error : "";

?>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script>
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('es_iksl_l5li2xygPS9cJE5MMWE8GSr');
</script> 

<div class="content_white register_wrapper">
    <div class="content_40" style="margin-left:350px;">
            <div class="content_gray" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <form method="post" name="payment_form" id="payment_form">
                            <div class="error" id="payment_error"></div>
                            <div class="box" style="padding: 15px 0;">    
                                    <label>Card Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="text_box" placeholder="Card Number" data-stripe="number" id="card_number" name="card_number" style="height: 40px;" />
                                    <div class="error" id="form_fname_error"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="box" style="padding: 15px 0;">    
                                    <label>Card CVC No</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="text_box" placeholder="CVC Number" data-stripe="cvc" id="cvc_number" name="cvc_number" style="height: 40px;" />
                                    <div class="error" id="form_lname_error"></div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="box" style="padding: 0px">
                                <label>Card Expiration Month/Year (MM/YYYY)</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box" style="padding: 15px 0; width: 30%;float: left;">
                                <input type="text" class="text_box" placeholder="Month-(MM)" data-stripe="exp-month" id="exp_month" name="exp_month" style="height: 40px;" />
                                    <div class="error" id="email_error1"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="box" style="padding: 15px 0; width: 50%;float: left;" >
                                <input type="text" class="text_box" placeholder="Year-(YYYY)" data-stripe="exp-year" id="exp_year" name="exp_year" style="height: 40px;" />
                                    <div class="error" id="form_password_error"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="box" style="text-align:center;">
                                <div class="submit_btn">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn_blue" id="submit_btn" value="Pay $20"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                    </form>
            </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#payment_form').submit(function(event) {
        console.log("start");
        var $form = $(this);
        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', true);
         Stripe.createToken({
                        number: $('#card_number').val(),
                        cvc: $('#cvc_number').val(),
                        exp_month: $('#exp_month').val(),
                        exp_year: $('#exp_year').val()
                    }, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });

        });
        // Call back function for stripe response.
            function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

                console.log("ststus"+status);
                if (response.error) {
                    // Re-enable the submit button
                    $('#submit_btn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    // Show the errors on the form
//                    stripeErrorDisplayHandler(response);
                    $('#payment_error').text(response.error.message);
//                    $('.subscribe_process').hide();
                } else {
                    var form = $("#payment_form");
                    // Getting token from the response json.

                    $('<input>', {
                            'type': 'hidden',
                            'name': 'stripeToken',
                            'value': response.id
                        }).appendTo(form);

                    // Doing AJAX form submit to your server.
                    form.get(0).submit();
                    return false;
                }
            }
</script>
```

When i run this file then run ready, and when i click on pay button then check card data and expiration month and year if it is ok then return stripeToken then resubmit form again then it will return error that is

> Fatal error: Class 'Stripe' not found in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\moviesaints\application\views\user\payment_precess.php
>   on line 12

Any idea give me solution.

Answer (score 2):

@rubai is absolutely right. Here is how you go when form is posted i.e you collect card information then in post action you work like this in controller:

//code

public function capture_payment(){

```
require_once APPPATH."third_party/stripe/init.php";
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_bB6syzsfoOqdQ4R57m7zE5Sp");      
$token = Stripe\Token::create(array(
  "card" => array(
  "number" => $this->input->post("credit_card_no"),
  "exp_month" => $this->input->post("expiry_month"),
  "exp_year" => $this->input->post("expiry_year"),
  "cvc" => $this->input->post("cvv")
    )
));
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      "source" => $token,
      "description" =>$this->session->userdata('doctor_name'))
);

// Charge the Customer instead of the card
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
   "amount" => 2000, // amount in cents, again
   "currency" => "usd",
   "customer" => $customer->id)
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please use this FCPATH in the place of APPPATH like

```
require_once(FCPATH.'libraries/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include the init.php not the stripe.php

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
```

And then call the stripe library like this

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('dm_wsdst_yJQB5mrfjpfQX2uMQHf3CbD');
```